# Laravel - Spatie permissions saying permission doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, laravel-permission

I've got a FormRequest class set up that is doing

```
public function authorize()
{
    return Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('can update users');
}
```

however it is throwing an exception

[image: the exception]

However in my database the permission definately exists

[image: image of database]

Is there some form of naming convention I need to be using or something I could be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: i think this is because of space try to replace space with - in permision names

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz No, the readme of the package itself uses spaces in permission names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing Laravel's cache, this can happen if permissions are added without being picked up by the cache.

Comment:  damn cache! I've now added a command to purge the permission cache

Answer (score 0):

As per @Tudor's suggestion try running `php artisan cache:clear` in your terminal to clear laravel cache

~Regards